# How to hide or disable the TimeHint in a toolkit TimeUpDown control in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, toolkit

I looked on the internet but I can find this nowhere : I would like to disable the **TimeHint** popup that shows the current time when entering focus on a `TimeUpDown` control. Something like : `<12:42AM>`

There is no *`TimeHintEnabled`* property, nor any kind of member that seems to control this. There **is** a `TimeHintContent` property, but it is readonly and seems empty at first.

My code is really simple :

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <toolkit:TimeUpDown Name="timeUpDown1"
                        Background="White"
                        Height="22"
                        MinWidth="55"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</Grid>
```

Maybe playing with the `Template` can do the trick, but I don't know how to do it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, thanks to Blend I found what I was looking for.
The Template can be easily modified by Blend, this part of the template is needed inside the xaml to hide the TimeHintPopup :

```
<Grid>
  <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="TimeHintStates">
      <VisualState x:Name="TimeHintOpenedUp">
        <Storyboard>
          <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"
                                         Storyboard.TargetName="TimeHintVisualElement">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="Collapsed"/>
          </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
      </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
  </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</Grid>
```

And your TimeUpDown should refer to this template :

```
    <toolkit:TimeUpDown Name="timeUpDown1" Background="White" Height="22" MinWidth="55" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource TimeUpDownStyle1}" />
```